# How to monitor data transmission in a browser using meteor.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, file-transfer

Is it possible - and how - to serve a file from a meteor/node.js server to a meteor driven client sided app and completely tell about every stage of a file transfer process, like: started download, download progress, file downloaded and saved successfully?
Thnx!

Answer (score 1):

The package `lepozepo:s3` provides this functionality. You can look at their code and how it tracks the upload percentage here: https://github.com/Lepozepo/S3/blob/master/client/functions.coffee#L114

Comment: for me it's all about downloading at the moment. Do you think, monitoring download metrics is also possible with your proposed solution?

Comment: I'm not following your question. If you're asking about monitoring the speed of downloads, yes you'd just have to do some more math. If you're asking about how many simultaneous downloads, that's another story too big for this comment.

Comment: ah, ok. I would start simple, with one download only. and I wanted to get events for start-download, download-progress (%, kB), stop-dwonload, file-saved.

Comment: ok cool. yeah, if you look at the link i provided it starts at the exact line where `lepozepo:s3` initiates all of the methods you'll need to track that.

Comment: so "upload" from the server side means "download" from the client side? or does "load" means the download...?